# computing number of nodes which can be reached by a specific node in a directed graph for each node

Tags: algorithm, graph

In a directed graph (suppose it has lots of cycles) I need to compute number of nodes which can be reached by specific node for each node. How can I do that with minimal effort? Which algorithm do I need to use?

Note: I think a reasonable algorithm for this problem should recursively compute this numbers(like result for 'node a' depends on that of 'node b' if a is connected to b).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm you're looking for is called the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), a very nice and efficient dynamic programming algorithm. It can be used to calculate the set of nodes reachable from each individual node in a graph (the [*transitive closure*](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/transitive-closure.shtml)), although it's more often used to calculate the shortest paths from each individual node in a graph to all other nodes.

(Edit: the Floyd-Warshall algorithm is more complicated than it needs to be for your uses, because it's been extended a bit by Floyd to calculate shortest paths. You may find [this page](http://datastructures.itgo.com/graphs/transclosure.htm) helpful, which only describes the "Warshall" part of the algorithm - the part you need.)

I happen to be studying it right now for class and have the paper on my desk. The recurrence for the transitive closure version of F-W is:

```
T(i,j,k) = T(i,j,k-1) ∨ (T(i,k,k-1) ∧ T(k,j,k-1))
```

Where `T(a,b,c)` is true if and only if there is a path from a to b using only the first c vertices in the graph (you must give them an arbitrary numbering before running the algorithm).

Intuitively, the recurrence says that there's a path from i to j using the first k vertices if:

- there's a direct path between i and j, using the first k-1 vertices, OR
- there's a path between i and k, and a path between k and j, using the first k-1 vertices.

You can build up the entire 3-dimensional table of T(i,j,k) in the typical dynamic programming fashion, and then count all of the TRUE entries along the source node that you want (using the max k), to get the size of the transitive closure for that source node.

If you're still following my poor explanation, you can make the algorithm extremely efficient with a few tricks:

- It turns out that you don't need the k dimension in your table; you can just overwrite your same row of values over and over. Now the program would look like:

  `T(i,j) = T(i,j) || (T(i,k) && T(k,j))`
- If T(i,k) is 0 then you can skip the whole thing since nothing will change on that step.
- If T(i,k) is 1 then the new value will just be `T(i,j) || T(k,j)`. This can be done in huge chunks because block OR is extremely fast on modern processors.

Hope that helps...